# How force use "this" in coffeeScript?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, this, static-methods

I need to define one static method in MotherClass like that:

```
class @MotherClass
  @test = =>
    Foo.bar(this) # same with @
```

but if u try it: http://coffeescript.org/#usage, you will see, this is automaticly compile in "MotherClass".

So, it's the same, but not realy!

In fact, I have a ChildClass in inheritance with MotherClass

```
  @ChildClass extends @MotherClass
```

So ChildClass.test() is defined. But like that:

```
function() {
    return Foo.bar(MotherClass);
};
```

I need first param of Foo.bar is ChildClass in ChildClass (and ChildClass2 if I make ChildClass2 class...), not MotherClass. 
So I need dynamic this, not static.

How force write "this" in CoffeeScript?

thx.

EDIT: I found "burk !" solution ^^ => "eval('this')", but it's realy crapy way. How do better?

Comment: How do you call the `test` function, and what do you expect `this` in it to be?

Comment: test() is static method of MotherClass class (and Childclass too). Look at the code^^ I expect "this" contain dynamicly called class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the skinny arrow instead of the fat arrow:

```
class @MotherClass
  @test = ->
    Foo.bar(this)
```

The fat arrow makes your function bound to `MotherClass`.

Comment: oh... so easy. I thought => is required for keep my class in this context, but doesn't need^^ Good answer !